# python3 tkinter, trying to update a label

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've looked at some other answers here, but I'm not understanding how to do this. This is the best I'm coming up with.

To eliminate off-subject comments, i prefer grid over pack, and I also like the widget.configure way of doing things, so that exactly one logical thing is accomplished with each line of code.

towards the end of the code, i have  self.root.update()   I have also left off the self. with no luck.

```
from tkinter import *

class Application:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame1 = Frame(master)
        frame1.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.btnQuit = Button(frame1)
        self.btnQuit.configure(text="QUIT")
        self.btnQuit.configure(fg="red")
        self.btnQuit.configure(command=frame1.quit)
        self.btnQuit.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.btnHi = Button(frame1)
        self.btnHi.configure(text="hi there")
        self.btnHi.configure(command="self.hello")
        self.btnHi.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.lblMessage = Label(frame1)
        self.lblMessage.grid(row=2, column=2)

        def hello(self):
            self.lblMessage.configure(text="hello there")
            self.root.update()

root = Tk()
program = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I've given an answer based on some guesswork. But in general, nobody can really help you if they don't know *what* isn't working (or working different from your expectation) in detail. What happens, what do you want to happen, if there's an error what is the exact and complete message, etc. - that kind of thing. You don't call customer service and simply state "Fix my thingy", do you?

Comment: One of the first rules of debugging event-based functions is to make sure the function you're trying to fix is actually being called. If you put a `print` statement inside your `hello` function it might tell you something you didn't know.

Comment: i added a print("in hello") as suggested. No output appeared in the console.

Comment: as far as "fix my thingie"... I've been in technical service for a little over 14 years. Normally, the customer bring it in because they don't know what's broke. An example using c++     "my program doesn't work!" cout < "hello world";

Comment: so, did you learn something when you didn't see any output? That perhaps your function wasn't being called? No matter how many things you try haphazardly, none will work because your function was never being called. The point is, be methodical and start with the basics. Make sure the code you're trying to fix is even being called. If not, the first step is to figure out why it's not being called.

Answer (score 2):

As stated above:

```
self.btnHi.configure(command="self.hello")
```

should be:

```
self.btnHi.configure(command=self.hello)
```

and mind the indent of the lines. But also:

```
self.v = StringVar()
self.lblMessage = Label(frame1, textvariable=self.v)
```

In your hello method, use:

```
self.v.set("hello there")
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to give the `command` option a callable object - not a string to be `eval`'d (which wouldn't work anyway since it'd be in a very different scope, e.g. with no/a different `self`). http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/button.html seems to confirm this.
2. The way your code is indented in your question, you define a local function `hello` inside `__init__` instead of defining it at class level (as a method). You need to remove one level of indentation starting with `def hello`

Answer (score 0):

Not clear to me what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to change the contents of a Label after it is created, then you need to use a StringVar() object.  Setting that to the Label's textvariable parameter (in its constructor) will mean that the Label updates whenever you update the value of the StringVar (using its set() method).

Comment: You do not *need* to use a `StringVar` -- it's possible to change the label using its `configure` method. Using an instance of `StringVar` is *a* way to solve the problem, but not *the only* way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
from tkinter import *

    class Application:
        def __init__(self, master):
            frame1 = Frame(master)
            frame1.grid(row=1, column=1)

            self.btnQuit = Button(frame1)
            self.btnQuit.configure(text="QUIT")
            self.btnQuit.configure(fg="red")
            self.btnQuit.configure(command=frame1.quit)
            self.btnQuit.grid(row=1, column=1)

            self.btnHi = Button(frame1)
            self.btnHi.configure(text="hi there")
            self.btnHi.configure(command=self.hello)
            self.btnHi.grid(row=2, column=1)

            self.lblMessage = Label(frame1)
            self.lblMessage.grid(row=2, column=2)

        def hello(self):
            self.lblMessage.configure(text="hello there")
            self.root.update()

    root = Tk()`enter code here`
    program = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```